# Неправильная установка NDK: Unity 2019.3.2f1

Tags: unity3d, android-ndk, unity-hub

В новых версиях Unity (такие как 2019.*.*) надо скачать Unity Hub и потом уже оттуда установить Unity и другие необходимые инструменты. Тут я установил Android SDK, NDK и ещё какие то инструменты. Проблема в том, что во время установки интернет отключился и в этот момент SDK был установлен, но вот NDK нет. Тогда уже скачивание оборвалось и NDK остался на острове как говорится. Галочка в Unity Hub стоит и её никак не убрать.

[image]
[<kbd>Открыть изображение</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbvZq.png)

Но вот сам Unity видит что NDK нету и заставляет установить.

[image]
[<kbd>Открыть изображение</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBOKl.png)

---

Вариант переустановки Unity всегда есть, но не факт что во время скачивания опять такое не случиться.
**Так есть какой нибудь другой способ установить NDK, или же как снимать эту галочку в Unity Hub, чтобы можно было ещё раз попробовать скачать?**

Comment: Установите отдельно юнити и добавьте по очереди нужные модули.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker это тоже самое что и переустановка. Такой вариант есть на последок но это не менее 4 часа у меня.

Comment: У меня на прошлой неделе получилось следующим образом перекачать SDK/NDK: удалил эти папки и перезапустил Хаб. Автоматически началась загрузка этих недостающих папок.

Comment: Вы просили альтернативу, хаб, к сожалению, не умеет удалять модули.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский я тоже так подумал. Удалил эти папки, но галочка всё ещё стоит.

Comment: @Арман у меня тоже "галочка" не снялась, но появилась синяя полоса прогресса сверху - типа идет скачивание. И скачалось.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский хорошо, скоро попробую

Comment: @Арман не знаю конкретно как у меня получилось. Но скорее всего дело в перезапуске Хаба (выгрузить из трея). Я думаю после запуска он проверил валидность установленных версий и докачал недостающие папки SDK/NDK.